# Assembly Reading User Input to Registers Gives Unexpected Value

Tags: assembly, x86-64

So I'm learning to use assembly and have written a simple function called _getInput as seen below:

```
 _getInput:
      movq    $0, %rax
      movq    $0, %rdi
      subq    $8, %rsp           
      leaq    -8(%rsp), %rsi
      movq    $8, %rdx
      addq    $8, %rsp
      syscall
      ret
```

I then have a _start function that calls this and saves the entered input to %r8 like so:

```
_start:
    call _getInput
    movq (%rsi), %r8
```

I've traced through this in GDB to see what the values of the registers are and have a few questions. First off, after I type an input and hit enter, %rsi has a value of 140737488347624. When I then run the next line to copy to %r8, the value of %r8 is 2609. Can someone explain what exactly is happening and where these values are coming from? I was expecting the value to be 49 (the ascii representation of 1), though maybe the new line character complicates this? Thank you!

Comment: `1` is just 1 byte but you load 8. Note that `2609` is `0xa31` in hex and as you can see the lowest byte is indeed `0x31` which is `49` decimal. That said, your stack manipulation is quite a mess. You allocate 8 bytes, then do not use it because you set `rsi` to 8 bytes lower. Then you even free those 8 bytes before reading the input and returning. Lucky for you, sysv abi provides 128 bytes of red zone but that's still quite wrong even if it happens to work :)

Comment: Your code looks really weird.  Why do you subtract from the stack pointer and then load an address below the stack pointer?  Also note that it's dangerous to assume that the space below the stack pointer survives a function call.

Comment: I was basing it off an example my professor gave but clearly a lot of it is unnecessary. I cleaned it up but the result is the same. The reason I want to allocate 8 bytes is to handle inputs of up to 8 bytes, I don't know ahead of time what the user will input. Do you know how I can handle this input to get the ascii value?

Comment: As I said, you already got the value. You just loaded too much. Use `movb (%rsi), %r8b` or `movzbl (%rsi), %r8d`